# Exporting listbox items into a dataset

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox, dataset

What is the easiest way to export the items from an `asp:listbox` into a dataset?

Comment: How are you getting the items into the listbox in the first place? Are they hard coded or are they databound?

Comment: A bit of both(!) That's the problem. Every item in the listbox has been copied from another listbox- either on its own or in a group. This original listbox was databound.

Comment: Ok, see my answer, should work all round

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly straight forward way that should work regardless of how you populate it, can't think of a faster way...

```
 public static DataTable GetListBoxItems(ListBox listBox)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Value");
        dt.Columns.Add("Text");
        dt.Columns.Add("Selected");
        dt.Columns.Add("Attributes");


        foreach (ListItem itm in listBox.Items)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = itm.Value;
            dr[1] = itm.Text;
            dr[2] = itm.Selected;
            dr[3] = itm.Attributes;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

OR with extension method:

```
 public static class Extensions
    {
        public static DataTable GetListBoxItems(this ListBox listBox)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Value");
            dt.Columns.Add("Text");
            dt.Columns.Add("Selected");
            dt.Columns.Add("Attributes");


            foreach (ListItem itm in listBox.Items)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = itm.Value;
                dr[1] = itm.Text;
                dr[2] = itm.Selected;
                dr[3] = itm.Attributes;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
ListBox1.GetListBoxItems();
```